# ReflectionException : Class env does not exist. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am currently trying to setup phpunit testing to test my API. The problem is that I am somehow not able to send the exact same request twice without having a problem.

I have tried changing up the phpunit.xml to see if there is a problem there without success, so I am doubting myself at the moment thinking I'm doing something wrong in the code itself.

```php
public function test_can_register_user() {
        $this->consoleLog('test_can_register_user');
        $generatedUser = str_random(5) . '@example.com';

        $data = [
            'name' => 'Test User',
            'email' => $generatedUser,
            'password' => 'test',
        ];

        var_dump($data);

        $expect = [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Thanks for signing up! Please check your email to complete your registration.',
        ];

       $request = $this->post('/api/auth/register', $data)
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson($expect);

       return $generatedUser;
    }

    /**
     * @depends test_can_register_user
     * @param $generatedUser
     */
    public function test_can_not_register_same_email($generatedUser) {
        $this->consoleLog('test_can_not_register_same_email');

        $data = [
            'name' => 'Test User',
            'email' => $generatedUser,
            'password' => 'test',
        ];

        var_dump($data);

        $expect = [
            'success' => false,
            "error" => [
                "email" => [
                "The email has already been taken."
                ]
            ]
            ];

       $request = $this->post('/api/auth/register', $data);
       var_dump($request->json());
       $request->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

```xml
     <php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="false"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
```

Expected result is to get a status 200 back. The actual result in the console is as followed:

```
Running test:
test_can_not_register_same_email
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Test User"
  ["email"]=>
  string(17) "C4v67@example.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}

ReflectionException : Class env does not exist
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:779
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:658
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:609
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:759
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1222
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:519
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php:24
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:60
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:60
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:455
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:61
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Telescope.php:263
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Telescope.php:222
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Telescope.php:270
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Telescope.php:294
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Watchers\CacheWatcher.php:45
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:360
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:209
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php:497
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php:107
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter.php:82
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter.php:39
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php:52
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:684
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:659
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:625
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:614
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php:36
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:57
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:345
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:195
 D:\Yeagger\yeagger-api\tests\Unit\UserTest.php:67
```

Comment: For some reason commenting App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class in app.php fixes the problem.

Comment: Something similar to this happened to me before, I belive the issue was in config and bootstrap caching, as this was something called inside an Event, so I ran the normal composer dumpautoload and php artisan config:clear / php artisan config:cache and it fixed everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will definitely try this out.

Answer (score 12):

put `dd($exception);` in `App\Exceptions\Handler::report()`
It gives you a better error message.
There was an error in `filesystem` config for me!

Comment: This worked for me. Otherwise the real error is not shown. I got a config error, too.

Comment: You'd be looking for `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`  at approximately line 220, and `dd($e);` unless your stacktrace indicates otherwise?

Comment: Really helped in debugging

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed by these commands:

```
php artisan clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Six of us on my dev team spent an hour trying to find how to fix this before I found your answer. php artisan clear was EXACTLY the answer we needed. 

I was using env('APP_ENV') in a config file, and it worked when it was written but then didn't after an update. Interestingly, app()->environment() worked as an attempt until I did an artisan optimize or artisan config:clear, then I got a message that the env class didn't exist.

I'd be super interested in an explanation. Anyone want to show how smart they are?

Answer (score 2):

for me it got fixed after setting PHPUnit

```
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

Comment: on which line you put this

Comment: Did it for me too. @Abdul - I added it in phpunit.xml at the end of the <php> block

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same by updating the composer

```
composer update
```